# Why do I need to put @NamedQuery on Entity class?

Tags: jpa, named-query

I am currently learning about JPA NamedQueries and tried to use it in GuestServlet:

```
Query getGuests =  em.createNamedQuery("myq");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Guest> guests = getGuests.getResultList();
```

It works when I put the @NamedQuery in Entity class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(
    name="myq",
    query = "SELECT g FROM Guest g")
public class Guest {
  ...
}
```

But when I try to use it in Servlet as following:

```
@WebServlet({"/GuestServlet","/guest"})
@NamedQuery(
        name="myq",
        query = "SELECT g FROM Guest g")
public class GuestServlet extends HttpServlet {...}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [myq]
```

Why am I forced to put @NamedQuery in Entity class while I use it in Servlet ?

Comment: You are not forced to. You may do that to seperate code and sql and call a returning query by its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GuestServlet is not managed by your jpa provider. Hibernate (or whatever) simply isn't aware of the named query.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [documentation of @NamedQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html):

> Specifies a static, named query in the Java Persistence query
> language. Query names are scoped to the persistence unit. The
> NamedQuery annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped
> superclass.

The annotation is copied to the persistence unit. The Servlet is outside of this scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in [`@NamedQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html) Javadoc. Namely,

> The NamedQuery annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped superclass.